# How can I create perspective images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, image-editing

How can I create an image like this?

[image]

I use GIMP. Are there any plugins to do this? If not, are there any other ways to accomplish this, such as in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming question.

Hint: Take a look at the perspective tool in The GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple 3d transform rotation with a drop shadow.

If you have word 2007, it's very easy.  Import your picture, select "Picture Effect"->"3D Rotation"->"Perspective" and then "Picture Effect"->Shadow

Do that to the 3 images you want, drag them to where you want, and save it as a picture.

Comment: hey thanks... i ms office... i got it through GIMP using "perspective tool". thanks anyways...!